# Google App scripts: Unable to preserve Leading zeros since it is automatically removed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am new to google script. I have a scenario like the below.

I have Sheet1 with Column A and B. Usually I try to store decimal values in to it. I mean integer part in column-A and decimal part in Column-B

For example:

Scenario-1:
It the value is 23.75 then Column-A should be 23 and ColumnB would be 75

Scenario-2:
If the value is 22.00 then Column-A should be 22 and ColumnB would be 00

I tried like this

```
 sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
        column = sheet.getRange("B:B");
        column.setNumberFormat("@");
        sRange = "O1:O" + 65;
        cell = sheet.getRange(sRange);
        cell.setValue("00");
```

This works fine for scenario-1, but for scenario-2 it displays only one zero (leading zero is automatically removed). I tried to change the complete column formatting to plain text but no luck.
I am strugging to achieve this for the past two days. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try setting the number format on the columns to a custom number format of `00`. Usually the format is `#` or `#,###.00` or similar. The `#` represents an optional digit. The `0` represents a required digit. [Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: Also, you should be declaring your variables with `var` so you don't create unintended global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an apostrophe:

```
cell.setValue("'00");
```

might be considered adequate.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround but is any way we can solve this.