# Is it possible to insert a Google Apps Script array value into a Sheet cell as plain text?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Put simply, I am working in Google Apps script, and I have an array value. I want to insert the array value into a sheet cell and the end result being the cell is set to plain text.

Everything about my code works, but this line refuses to result in a plain text output:

```
function minimal()
{ 
   const allFormResponses = fetchFormResponses();  //loads numbers from form output into a 2D array
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("All");  
   var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
   for(var d = 0; d < allFormResponses.length; d++) 
   {
      var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
      for (var e = 0, col = 1; e < allFormResponses[d].length; e++, col++)
      {
         sheet.getRange(lastRow,col).setValue(JSON.stringify(allFormResponses[d][e].itemResponse.toString())).setNumberFormat("@");     
      }
   } 
}
```

I have also tried just formatting the entire column after each value is added and that doesn't work either.

Feeling stumped and I feel like it's probably something dumb I am missing.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: why are you setting the values to string first and after that changing the format to number? `itemResponse.toString()).setNumberFormat("@");`. If I remember correctly, [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)) will *Sets the number or date format to the given formatting string.* so the result will not be plain text anymore but number format.

Comment: However, it will be good to have more information or an example.

Comment: @GiselleValladares The .toString() was just desperation, trying to make the output conform. I'd read on SO and elsewhere that .setNumberFormat("@") = "Plain text" but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I think the `.toString` is okay since this will change the array to plain text, but the  `.setNumberFormat` will change any string format to number format. So it is usually used like this `setNumberFormat(newNumberFormat);`, and `.toString()` method should return a string representation. You can review more [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/js/string_tostring.php). Because of this I will say that `.toString() = "Plain Text"`

Comment: @Dave, are you getting the values as JSON, or is it returned as an "Array"? Because I was reviewing the documentation of FormApp, and I don't see that it returns a JSON but just arrays.

Comment: @Dave, have you try using `.setNumberFormat('@STRING@');` in the cell fist. Like adding in the line after the `for` -> `sheet.getRange(lastRow,col).setNumberFormat('@STRING@');` and after that Rubén suggestion: 
`sheet.getRange(lastRow,col).setValue(`'${allFormResponses[d][e].itemResponse}`);`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
sheet.getRange(lastRow,col).setValue(allFormResponses[d][e].itemResponse).setNumberFormat("@");
```

by

```
sheet.getRange(lastRow,col).setValue(`'${allFormResponses[d][e].itemResponse}`);
```

Related

- [Format a Google Sheets cell in plaintext via Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13758913/1595451)
- [Google App scripts: Unable to preserve Leading zeros since it is automatically removed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54438867/1595451)

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Cell is still set to "Automatic" in Sheets, causing the number to be...a number.